# Redis keyspace notification expiration not firing

Tags: redis

I am looking at this page:  https://redis.io/topics/notifications

I have the following line set in my config file:

```
notify-keyspace-events "Kx"
```

When I do this (and then run my application that eventually expires some keys), I see no events:

```
redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__keyspace*__:*expire*'
```

However, when I set my config to this:

```
notify-keyspace-events "Kg"
```

And then run the same app and redis-cli command, I do see events:

```
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:wca:sessions:expires:9d73fefc-459d-4bf4-83ef-b8fcbf06b997","expire"
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:wca:sessions:expires:9d73fefc-459d-4bf4-83ef-b8fcbf06b997","expire"
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:idp:sessions:expires:52dbe449-4616-41ef-bfa6-1d7a16a89f8a","expire"
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:idp:sessions:expires:52dbe449-4616-41ef-bfa6-1d7a16a89f8a","expire"
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:idp:sessions:expires:52dbe449-4616-41ef-bfa6-1d7a16a89f8a","expire"
"pmessage","__keyspace*__:*expire*","__keyspace@0__:spring:session:idp:sessions:expires:52dbe449-4616-41ef-bfa6-1d7a16a89f8a","expire"
```

I understand that the expirations don't necessarily happen right when the TTL has elapsed.  But I'm not sure that explains what I'm seeing -- my redis-cli is looking only for "expire" events, and it consistently sees them when (and only when) I notify generic commands.  That's too chatty for my app; I just want to see expires.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious what happens when you do `AK`

Comment: @Thymine IIRC I tried that earlier today.  It worked, but it was very chatty.

Answer (score 9):

You subscribed to the wrong channel.

There're two kinds of notification:

- **Key-space notification**: the channel is `__keyspace@<db>__:<key>`
- **Key-event notification**: the channel is `__keyevent@<db>__:<event>`

If you want to get all expired key notification, you have two choices:

#### use key-space notification

1. enable key-space notification: `config set notify-keyspace-events Kx`
2. subscribe to the channel: `psubscribe __keyspace@*__:*`

#### use key-event notification

1. enable key-event notification: `config set notify-keyspace-events Ex`
2. subscribe to the channel: `psubscribe __keyevent@*__:expired`

Comment: Thanks.  I did "notify-keyspace-events Kx" (per the doc), and I didn't see anything.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you subscribed to the wrong channel. You should `psubscribe __keyspace@*__:*`

Comment: Ah. I see the difference. So I guess my question is: when I added the "g" it worked. Is the generic "expire" different than the expire that would be caught by the "x"? If not, I don't understand why the exact same psubscribe saw "expire" events only when I added the g. (I.e. why do I have to notify all generic events when all I'm interested in is expire?)

Comment: when subscribing, can we set a pattern like `__*myeventkeyonly*@0__:expired`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to "`__keyevent@0__:expired`" rather than "`__keyevent@0__:expire`"

```
127.0.0.1:6379> subscribe __keyevent@0__:expired
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "__keyevent@0__:expired"
3) (integer) 1

1) "message"
2) "__keyevent@0__:expired"
3) "mykey"
```

Refer this doc. I was also facing same issue. I tried the solution from this link it worked https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/1855