# Redis: Expiration of secondary indexes

Tags: redis

I'm curious about best practices as far as expiring secondary indexes in Redis.

For instance, say I have object IDs with positions that are only considered valid for 5 seconds before they expire. I have:

```
objectID -> hash of object info
```

I set these entries to automatically expire after 5 seconds.

I also want to look up objects by their zip code, so I have another mapping:

```
zipCode -> set or list of objectID
```

I know there's no way to automatically expire elements of a set, but I'd like to automatically remove objectIDs from that zip code mapping when they expire.

What is the standard practice for how to do this? If there were an event fired upon expiration I could find the associated zip code mapping and remove the objectID, but not sure there is (I will be using Go).

Comment: What I think I might do is a) when somebody looks up the zip code and finds the associated objectIDs, check each on the primary objectID->hash mapping to see if it's valid, and if not delete it from the zip code mapping. b) periodically go through all of the zip codes and remove anything that's not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there were an event fired upon expiration I could find the associated zip code mapping and remove the objectID, but not sure there is

YES, there is an expiration notification, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526243/redis-keyspace-notification-expiration-not-firing/51533803) for an example.

You can have a client subscribing to the [expiration event](https://redis.io/topics/notifications), and delete items from the *zipCode* set or list.

However, this solution has two problems:

1. The notification is NOT reliable. If the client disconnects from Redis, or just crashes, client will miss some notifications. In order to make it more reliable, you can have multiple clients listening to the notification. If one client crashes, others can still remove items from *zipCode*.
2. It's NOT atomic. There's a time window between the key expiration and removing items from *zipCode*.

If you're fine with these 2 problems, you can try this solution.

Comment: I'm realizing that the expiration event will only give me the key itself and not its value (and since it's expired I can't look up the value either), so this may not work for my purpose, as my intention was to extract the zip code from the value and use it to directly go to my zipCode set.

Comment: @vmayer You can use an extra HASH to build a map from *objectID* to *zipCode*. When you get an expiration event, search the HASH to get the *zipCode*, and remove it from the HASH and also remove it from the *zipCode* mapping.